# How to use constraint layout in ListView

Tags: java, android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I've been using Linear layout for my listview which is perfectly fine if my data is only like 
[image]
But when I do want to format my data for ConstraintLayout, it takes a whole page to scroll not like the Linear layout.
[image]

Example code
 `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.019"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="312dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="668dp"
        android:text="Number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="July"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />`
```

Comment: Is it a custom adapter with bean?

Comment: post your full xml code.

Comment: It is really bad idea to use Constraint layout in ListView items. It can slow your scrolling performance.

Comment: in UI file, take any layout and put ListView tag in it., after it bind the data to ListView programatically. There is no need to set anything to scroll.

Comment: @MayurRaval I appreciate you letting me know about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using constraint layout , make sure you are giving right constraint to the view . As i  can see , you halve given bottom_to_bottomOf = " parent" Which makes the view to acquire the complete height of parent view .

Just remove         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" from your view .

You need to provide min of three constraint to any view . Check if this is working fine or not ???

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.019"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="312dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="668dp"
    android:text="Number"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewName"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="July"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

For better Understanding  on constraint layout  you can use this reference : https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013

Additionally , you dont need to write

```
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
```

Instead you can use   android:layout_margin="8dp" which cover the above four margin .

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. I appreciate the ConstraintLayout link.